# Spring Cloud not detecting the git repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have a `spring-boot` project which uses `spring-cloud` to manage the properties in a centralized place.

I have configured the app as below

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

and the `application.properties` as below

```
spring.application.name=spring-cloud-config-server
server.port=8888
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///ebs/payment-config-server-git
```

But when I run the jar, the application log stops at,

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.0.RELEASE)

2020-06-08 19:36:38.641  INFO 4278 --- [           main] c.h.t.c.ConfigServerApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-06-08 19:36:40.303  INFO 4278 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=cb4015b1-4a5b-3c4c-a050-3196b94db932
2020-06-08 19:36:40.973  INFO 4278 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8888 (http)
2020-06-08 19:36:41.001  INFO 4278 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-06-08 19:36:41.002  INFO 4278 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.35]
2020-06-08 19:36:41.128  INFO 4278 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-06-08 19:36:41.128  INFO 4278 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2460 ms
2020-06-08 19:36:41.608  INFO 4278 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-06-08 19:36:42.649  INFO 4278 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2020-06-08 19:36:42.718  INFO 4278 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8888 (http) with context path ''
2020-06-08 19:36:42.738  INFO 4278 --- [           main] c.h.t.c.ConfigServerApplication          : Started ConfigServerApplication in 5.573 seconds (JVM running for 6.371)
```

It is supposed to log the repository location from where it reads the properties from. But it is not printing those logs and I am not able to read any properties from the application.

What is the mistake in my configuration file?

Thank You.

PS: Git origin is not set. There is no remote for the git repository

Comment: only when an application makes a request and likely only on the client side.

Comment: What? Can you please explain?